# ScrollView height 0 even when fill_parent

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a linearlayout A containing a imageview and scrollview. The scrollview contains a second linearlayout B
The idea is to have a fixed header while the linearLayout B contains multiple views that match exactly the height of the scrollview. See it as a tabview where all tabs are after each other in a scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/logoImg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scrollLinear"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to achieve this by calling getHeight on the scrollView and then set this height to each view in the linearLayout B but getHeight always returns 0.
Anyone an idea what's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it... you want the equivalent of a vertical tabview ? why use a scrollview then?

Comment: Well, I want an animated tabview. If you click on a tab the correct tab is shown by scrolling the scrollview to the right position. I think this looks nice. I know I can use a tabview to achieve the same functional effect but not the same visual effect.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is very old, but I'll give it a try :)
Wouldn't it be lack of "fillViewport" in ScrollView?

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:fillViewport="true" 

    >
```